# How to control Kuka robot with Moveit?

Tags: ros, moveit, kuka, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to control KUKA KR10 using MOVEIT.  I am now able to control the joints using rqt_joint_trajectory controller.  Now I want to send the robot in random position, using Rviz and moveit, and have Gazebo simulation of the robot follow the same path too.  I have a controller named arm_position_controller in namespace kuka_kr10. I put them in this namespace, because I could not simulate the robot in Gazebo without it.

However, I cannot control the Robot using rviz only.  My guess is, this is because rviz is publishing  joint_state to  namespace "kr10/joint_state" while the robot waits for messages on "joint_state". I do not know, if this assumption is correct, because when i manually change the joint state using rqt_joint_trajectory_controller, the change is reflected on rviz(however not in gazebo). Now my idea was to simply remap "kr10/joint_state" to "joint_state" and hope it works. Apparently it is not that easy. Does anyone have an idea, how do I go on about doing this?

I found [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/345728/connect-real-kuka-to-moveit/) on how to achieve it using EKI but I am using RSI and the second answer mentions robtot_interface_streaming.launch  which is not to be found in KUKA Industrial Package. Is there any easy way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369348/how-to-control-kuka-robot-with-moveit?/) by [brahpra](https://answers.ros.org/users/62923/brahpra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-01-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PRA008](https://answers.ros.org/users/108380/pra008/) on 2022-06-17**:
Now can you follow [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/345728/connect-real-kuka-to-moveit/?fbclid=IwAR0AeMjOXTOTv0r8K7K7v_h2vlu8y4xUfwzdFFnGoDUiy_LFFJaAZdDNCrg) using rsi? I'm trying to do it, but I'm wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve it following [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/345728/connect-real-kuka-to-moveit/). robot_interface_streaming.launch can be found [here](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/kuka_experimental/blob/kr6r900sixx_moveit_rsi_convenience/kuka_rsi_hw_interface/launch/robot_interface_streaming.launch).  [This Discussion](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues/56) helped me troubleshoot the fact, that I was unable to control my robot using rqt_joint_trajectory_controller.  If anyone encounters the same problem,  feel free to leave a comment. I guess,  I kinda understand what was going on now.

---

Originally posted by [brahpra](https://answers.ros.org/users/62923/brahpra/) with karma: 36 on 2021-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-03-25**:
Hello @brahpra,

I am facing the same issue. Can you help me to resolve the Kuka issue? I am using Kuka RSI.